# Nth child CSS - Apply styles to every 2 childs

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am trying to apply styles with nth child to every 3rd, 4th and 5th child, then to every 8th, 9th, 10th. Then 13th, 14th, 15th... 
So apply styles to 3 childs, then jump to childs and apply the same styles to another 3 childs, etc.

Here's an image that explain what I am trying to do: apply styles to the orange childs, when they are going to be hundreds of childs [image]

Comment: Hi. Your question while interesting does not provide too much information for being able to provide a good answer. Please share your code and also show us what you've tried or at least a general direction of your thoughts on solving this. Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to explain... Basically I would like to add some styles to the orange childs. The image shows how my template it's going to look and I am trying to apply a different css to those childs, but I can't find the way to do it with nth child...

Comment: I'm taking that all the children have same classes and styling for now, except for the width and color?

Comment: You can use math formulas in nth-child: https://jsfiddle.net/fvfgevzh/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the above result using `nth-of-type` property of css.
eg: using `nth-of-type(5n+3)`, I'm telling the css to be applied on every 5th element starting from number 3.

```css
.test{
    width: 300px;
    border: 5px solid cyan;
    padding: 25px;
}
.test:nth-of-type(5n+3) {
    width: 300px;
    border: 5px solid orange !important;
    padding: 25px;
}
.test:nth-of-type(5n+4) {
    width: 300px;
    border: 5px solid orange !important;
    padding: 25px;
}
.test:nth-of-type(5n+5) {
    width: 300px;
    border: 5px solid orange !important;
    padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

For further reading, refer this: http://nthmaster.com/